# Do horizontally scrolling tabs on mobile have issues with long labels

Tags: usability, mobile-application, tabs, gestures

Designing tab navigation for a mobile app feature, and some of the labels are going to be quite lengthy. I'm curious if this would cause usability issues for users who might not know that you can swipe navigation horizontally to see more.

Is this UI pattern common enough for users to know this intuitively. if not, how can I overcome this possible issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For UI components like image galleries or carousels this is a standard design pattern because you are talking about content that is normally simple (in its interaction) and you have lots of them.

For UI components like menu or navigation, you are better off trying to make the location and position of the interface fixed for easier learnability and findability.

There are alternate strategies like using icons or truncating the text (...) to save space, but you really have to look at all your tab items and come up with a strategy that works best for current and future designs.

Answer (score 2):

I once managed a product that used this pattern (some menu items were off-screen). The off-screen tabs received very little engagement.

Some alternatives might include:

- Show three/four most important labels and use a hamburger menu for everything else
- Put everything in a hamburger menu